# Do I need a transit UK visa?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, ethiopian-citizens

I’m traveling from France to the US through London Heathrow airport. I have an Ethiopian passport but also a USA visa and French residency permit/ card. I wanted to know if I still needed a transit visa even though I have these documents?
I saw on the gov page that I need a visa if I have an Ethiopian passport but there are exceptions: if I have a USA visa or if I hold an EEA residence permit. Thank you in advance for the information.